# Change the amount of data in SQL via PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

Hello i have a table in sql called premium now when "user" with premium (in the table that there is 1 number is premium and 0 is not) then in the code before you i have an avant that every hour when clicked need to get something in return in this case this is a table called userMana Now i want premium name Will receive more (that is paid money) then is this way correct?

The first part I tried and after that I used the bottom part

```php
if (isset($_GET['daily'])) {
    if ($user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)) {
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `hourEvent` = ?, `userMana` = `userMana` + 10, `userCitizens` = `userCitizens` + 1 WHERE userId = ?")->execute([$time, $user->userId]);
        header("Location: /אזור-משחק/בסיס");
    } else if ($user->premium > 0) {
       if ($user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)) {
            $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
            $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `hourEvent` = ?, `userMana` = `userMana` + 101, `userCitizens` = `userCitizens` + 1 WHERE userId = ?")->execute([$time, $user->userId]);
            header("Location: /אזור-משחק/בסיס");
        }
    }
}

################################ Separator ###########################

if (isset($_GET['daily'])) {
    if ($user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)) {
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `hourEvent` = ?, `userMana` = `userMana` + 10, `userCitizens` = `userCitizens` + 1 WHERE userId = ?")->execute([$time, $user->userId]);
        header("Location: /אזור-משחק/בסיס");
    }
    if ($user->premium > 0 && $user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)) {
        $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
        $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `hourEvent` = ?, `userMana` = `userMana` + 11, `userCitizens` = `userCitizens` + 1 WHERE userId = ?")->execute([$time, $user->userId]);
        header("Location: /אזור-משחק/בסיס");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using MySQLi or PDO? Passing an array of parameter values to `execute()` only works in PDO, not MySQLi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will not work properly.

The `else if` condition will only be tested when `$user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)` returns `false`. But the nested `if` block is only executed when this same expression returns `true`. Unless the result of this changes between these two tests, the second one can never succeed. So premium users will never get a bonus.

The second version will give *two* bonuses to premium users. They'll first get the same bonus of `10` that everyone gets, then they'll get an additional `11` bonus because they're premium users. I think it would be clearer to write it like this:

```
$normal_bonus = 10;
$premium_bonus = 21;
if (isset($_GET['daily']) && $user->checkHours($user->hourEvent)) {
    $bonus = $user->premium ? $premium_bonus : $normal_bonus;
    $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `users` SET `hourEvent` = ?, `userMana` = `userMana` + ?, `userCitizens` = `userCitizens` + 1 WHERE userId = ?")->execute([$time, $bonus, $user->userId]);
    header("Location: /אזור-משחק/בסיס");
}
```

This removes lots of duplicate code between the cases, and only executes one query to add to `userMana`.

Comment: Hi, if I want to do this on another parameter it's almost the same thing right?
instead of :
`$normal_bonus`
I do
`$normal_bonus1`
Then gives a question mark (?) To the same change in SQL
Then he writes:
`$bonus1` instead of `$bonus`

Right? Or it's more than that.

Comment: That's exactly right. You can use any number of variables and parameters.